# stop page from jumping back to top when empty <a> tag is clicked

Tags: css, html

The title says it all, how would I make it using only html, no JAVASCRIPT, to stop the page from jumping back to the top if a user clicks on an empty  tag?  So for example, if at the very bottom of my site, I have a link that is empty, but click on it, it takes be clear back up to the top...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to stop # links that call javascript functions from jumping to top of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150229/how-to-stop-links-that-call-javascript-functions-from-jumping-to-top-of-page)

Comment: So where is the link supposed to take you?

Comment: It's not supposed to jump anywhere...if I click on an empty <a href> link - I want it to stay put and not jump up to the top of the page.

Comment: @user2732875 Context matters here. What's the point of the link? Also, show your code; `<a href>` won't make the page jump, it will reload the current page.

Comment: You stop it by removing the empty `<a>` tag (whatever you mean by that). If you think you cannot remove it, you need to post a new question that explains what you are really doing (with relevant HTML and JavaScript included).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution to this would simply put in the a tag:

```
<a href="#a">Title</a>
```

In doing this, it won't scroll your page back to the top. To have it scroll back to the top, take out the a after the # symbol...so it would look like this:

```
<a href="#">Title</a>
```

That is the best explanation I can give you without any code provided from you.

Give that a try and it should work with what you are asking for...No javascript is needed. In fact you can even make the #a jump to a different location if you'd like on your page :)

**UPDATE:**

This may suit you better!  Add this to either a js file or add it inline with you html document.

Separate js file (just make sure to call it externally on your html file):

```
$('#Add_Your_Id_Or_Class_Here').removeAttr('href');
```

Example: `$('#link a').removeAttr('href');` or `$('.link a').removeAttr('href');` or even `$('a').removeAttr('href');`

Now, if you want to achieve this via inline on your html file, simply do this:

```
<script>
    $('#Add_Your_Id_Or_Class_Here').removeAttr('href');
</script>
```

Again, you can use any of the examples above as well.  In fact there are many ways you can achieve this now that I think about it...Hope that helps :)

Comment: `href="#a"` is a hacky workaround, definitely not something that should be taught to beginners. (besides, `#a` might exist)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the example - instead I'm using `<a href="#stay">Link</a>` and in doing so, when I click on it, it stays put! -- Thank you again!

Comment: I think better solution is `<a href="#/">Title</a>`

Comment: @Wesley Murch, I am kinda having a different problem. My question is at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37964120/3697102

Answer (score 1):

If your link isn't supposed to be linked (such as when it's just a placeholder for where a link could be) then you should not add an `[href]` attribute to the `<a>` element