# How to prevent a page from jumping to top when showing or hiding elements using jQuery fade option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

There are many questions on this and I have tried them.

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**

I am using jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut options to hide divs and show a list using the jquery below but the page keeps jumping to the top. The list that will be displayed is dynamic.

I tried with `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` but of no use.

I tried changing anchor tags to span tags but then the second `onClick` function doesn't work.

Is this because my content length is dynamic which is making it look like a jump or is it a real jump?

Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div id="action_bar">
    <div id="cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i><div class="total">20</div></div>
    <a href="" id="nav">CATEGORIES</a>
    <div id="filter"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i><div class="total">1</div></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="category1" class="category" data-categories="SPL">
        <img src="images/c_w.png"><div class="category_description">Chef's Special</div>
    </div>

    <div id="category2" class="category" data-categories="LCH">
        <img src="images/l_w.png"><div class="category_description">Lunch</div>
    </div>

    <div id="category3" class="category" data-categories="SNK">
        <img src="images/s_w.png"><div class="category_description">Snacks</div>
    </div>

    <div id="category4" class="category" data-categories="DNR">
        <img src="images/d_w.png"><div class="category_description">Dinner</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="items">
        <!-- Menu List -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.category', function(){
        var category = $(this).data('categories');
        //alert(category);
        $('.category').fadeOut(300);
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "./assets/listproducts.php",
               data: {cat: category},
               cache: false,
               success: function(response){
                   //console.log(response);
                   $('#nav').html('<- BACK').addClass('back');
                   $('.items').html(response).delay(400).fadeIn(300);
               }
        });
    });

    $('.back').on('click', function(e){
        $('.items').fadeOut(300);
        $('.category').html(response).delay(400).fadeIn(300);
        $('#nav').html('CATEGORIES').removeClass('back');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.items
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: The `items` fade out when you hit back?

Comment: The fading works fine but it keeps jumping to the top.

Comment: If you're happy using the browser console, add a `debugger;` statement inside the `.on('click'..` handler and inside the 'success:' callback function - otherwise put some `alerts("step x")` (etc) in there to see exactly what's been called and when.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `.back` onclick is never firing.

It doesn't work either time (as an `a` or `span`) - when it's an `a`, the default click will fire which will take you to the top.

This is because when you call `$('.back').on('click'..)` there isn't a `.back` element to wire up to as you've not yet added that class to your back button.

You need to use event delegation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/2181514

Change your event wire up to:

```
$("document").on("click", ".back", function....
```

which will then pick up dynamically changed classes

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if your `click` event on `.back` is registered at all since when event is bound, `.back` does not exist. Hence its as good as a click on link which has no `href`.

You need to delegate click on `.back` to the `document`. This delegation is needed because you are adding the `back` class dynamically.

```
 $(document).on('click','.back', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.items').fadeOut(300);
        $('.category').html(response).delay(400).fadeIn(300);
        $('#nav').html('CATEGORIES').removeClass('back');

    });
```

Comment: It still keeps happening the same.

Comment: I tried using a button element but then the second javascript is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do in html5, is use an anchor tag without the `href` attribute.
In CSS you can use `cursor: pointer` to compensate for that.
Then in JavaScript there's suddenly no need anymore for `event.preventdefault`

Comment: As a note: an `a` without an href cannot be focused using the keyboard `tab` key, so may fall foul or any accessbility requirements.   In general, don't do this.

Comment: That's correct, I used to do `href="void(0)"` so you don't need return false or preventDefault. if focus and usability (tablet/phone) is important => preventdefault is your friend to counter empty href or `href="#"` which makes the page jump to the top.

Comment: Yep the page I am making is responsive so I have to account for tablets and phones.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution is to set `href="#/"` on an anchor tag, which would work. However, using anchor tags where they are not needed (if you use `<a>` there should exist some clickable link) is not good practice for SEO.

Also, you could use `e.preventDefault()`, but use it on all functions, not only on back click.

However, the better practice is to use `<input type="button" />`, you eliminate those jumping problems and do better SEO.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't sound right. Have you tried removing href entirely?

Comment: Using a button it doesnt trigger the second click function neither the first function works properly(i.e; sometimes it scrolls up sometimes it doesnt)

Comment: any more help will be really appreciated.